# Objective-C Fast Enumeration Bubble Sort

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks, fast-enumeration

I'm trying to integrate some GCD into my code, and have found that a severe bottleneck is a bubble comparison I am performing between objects in a large array.  Here is the original code:

```
NSUInteger count = [arrayToDoWorkOn count];
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < count; j++)
    {
        [[arrayToDoWorkOn objectAtIndex:i] compare:[arrayToDoWorkOn objectAtIndex:j]];
    }
}
```

Get my drift?  So a lot of other fast enumeration tasks can be easily GCD'd by converting

```
for (id obj in array)
{
    [obj aMessage:stuff];
}
```

to:

```
[array enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop)
{
    [obj aMessage:stuff];
}];
```

Is there a way to convert my look-ahead-sorta-bubble-sorta-algorithm-thing to something that I can feed to a GCD block implementation?

Comment: This has nothing to do with GCD only blocks.

Comment: Hey Grimless, if my response answered your question, don't forget to mark it as the correct answer! ;)

Comment: WHOOPS.  Could have sworn I did that already.  Yesterday was pretty hectic.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend implementing your own sort if `NSArray` already has a built in method for it that will most likely sort faster than anything you can come up with. You can just use this:

```
NSArray *sortedArray = [arrayToDoWorkOn sortedArrayWithComparator:^(id firstObject, id secondObject) {
    /* comparison code (e.g. return [[firstObject title] compareTo:[secondObject title]], or something) */
}];
```

Now, if you need to use the objects during the sort, you're in for a pickle, but I'd recommend looking into sorts more efficient than a bubble sort (quick sort is a pretty good one).

---

Besides this, I think you're a bit confused about GCD. Writing and using a block does not inherently execute it with GCD; that has to be done manually (strictly speaking, a block is simply a collection of lines of code and does not inherently have anything to do with GCD; GCD simply uses blocks for execution). `NSArray`'s `enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` method most likely does not use GCD to enumerate the array (at least the reference gives no insight on this, so please prove me wrong), and if it does, it's not because you're supplying it with a block, but rather because that's how Apple chose to implement it. Most methods taking blocks do not use GCD to execute them.

I recommend you read the [Grand Central Dispatch (GCD) Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html) as well as Cocoa Samurai's [A Guide to Blocks and GCD](http://cocoasamurai.blogspot.com/2009/09/guide-to-blocks-grand-central-dispatch.html) to get greater insight into the specifics of the topic.

Comment: `-enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:` has no reason at all to use GCD. The variant that does use GCD is `-enumerateObjectsWithOptions:usingBlock:` with the `NSEnumerationConcurrent` option specified.

Comment: There we go; that's what I thought.

Comment: Ah, it seems I misread/misunderstood some of the GCD stuff I was looking into (still quite new to GCD).  Thanks for the insight.  After staring at the problem a while longer (and understanding a little more about GCD) I believe I have concluded that what I want can be achieved through blocks.  Thanks!